# How do i configure my PXE boot server to boot Windows PE?

Tags: grub2, pxe

I would like some advice. I run a PXE server to install multiple versions of Linux without a hitch. The way the PXE server is setup is as follows:

1. boot client PC from network
2. client PC downloads GRUB2 to local machine
3. GRUB2 displays a list of choices (debian10, 11, etc)
4. select menu entry to start install

I made a windows image/install scripts and put it on a samba share.
when i boot Windows PE from a USB device and mount the samba share then execute setup everything works fine.

The only problem i can not figure out is how to configure the grub.cfg file to boot into windowsPE.

I have no experience in GRUB so any help would be amazing!
This is what i currently have:

menuentry --hotkey=w 'Windows PE' {

terminal_output console

insmod chain

chainloader tftp://servername/path/to/PE/winpe/EFI/Boot/bootx64.efi

}

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Welcome to the Unix & Linux Stack!  Just a heads-up that Windows Subsystem for Linux is a different feature than you seem to be discussing.  I've removed that tag since it doesn't appear to have anything to do with your question, but if it does, please add it back and edit the question to include how WSL is in use.  Thanks!